# Webview load html from assets directory and send data to

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I'm trying to load a html page from the assets directory

```
public class ViewWeb extends Activity {  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);  
        WebView wv;  
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html");
    }  
  }
```

its work but i wont to send some text also for textbox. How to Do that? Pls help me!!!!

Comment: send some text also for textbox, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways.

**First way**

In javascript

```
function getParameters(query) {
    var parts = query.split('&');
    var params = {};
    for (var i = 0, ii = parts.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        var param = parts[i].split('=');
        var key = param[0];
        var value = param.length > 1 ? param[1] : null;
        params[decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    return params;
}
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var params = getParameters(document.location.search.substring(1));
    if(params.hasOwnProperty('text_box_value')) {
        var textBox = document.getElementById(<ID of your textbox>);
        textBox.value = params['text_box_value'];
    }
}
);
```

In Java code

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html?text_box_value=sometext");
```

**Second way**

In Java code

```
public class ViewWeb extends Activity {  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);  
        WebView wv;  
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        wv.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html");
    }  
}

private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function setText() {var textBox = document.getElementById('your textbox id'); textBox.value = '" + yourTextString + "';})()");
    }
}
```

Comment: out of this two which one is more secure??

Comment: all ways has same security level, because anyway you must make safe the string which you want to assign to textbox

Answer (score 0):

One way of  doing this is to have JavaScript bridge apis. Let say you have JS method in HTML like this :

```
function setText(message){
     // Set message to Text Box
}
```

You can Invoke this JS method from native code(Java) like this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setText(" + text + ")");
```